# How to convert an object to an array using either php or javascript?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm using Full Calendar to create events. This is my backend code in my controller, I'm using Laravel.

```
public function index() {

        $myInterviews = Interview::all()->where('candidate_user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $interviews = $myInterviews->toArray();

        return Response::json(array(
            'events' => $interviews,
        ), 200);

    }
```

For some reason, when there is only a single event, the json data gets returned as an Object instead of an array and so the event isn't being displayed on my Calendar, because with Full Calendar, the data needs to be inside of an array not an Object. If there's more than one event, everything works fine because the json data becomes an Array.

As you can see above I tried using the `toArray()` method to convert the data and if I die and dump `$interviews` it shows that it's an Array, which means the issue seems to be the `Response::json` part.

I also tried converting the response on the Vue js side using `Object.keys(obj)`,
but this also didn't work, the data returned was still an Object.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS:

```
// obj can be an array or an object
const arr = [].concat(obj)
```